# using yii2 findall and accessing the first element

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I wold like to identify the first element in a find all in yii2 but i havent fond out a way to do this,

This is the code:

```
$services = TblWorksTags::find()->where(["active"=>true])->all();
foreach ($services as $service){
    echo '<li>'.$service->name.'</li>
}
```

From the above code i would like it to have the first item having a different class that is like

```
$services = TblWorksTags::find()->where(["active"=>true])->all();
foreach ($services as $service) {
    //if its the first element
    echo '<li class="active">'.$service->name.'</li>  //this has a diffrent  <li>

    //for the other elements
    echo '<li>'.$service->name.'</li>
}
```

Comment: your second code in syntactically incorrect. `'` and `;` missed. Is it a TYPO?

Comment: Ive corrected the typo and it didnt fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through some `counter` like below:-

```
<?php
$services = TblWorksTags::find()->where(["active"=>true])->all();

$counter = 1;
foreach ($services as $service){
    if($counter ==1){
        //if its the first element
        echo '<li class="active">'.$service->name.'</li>';  // quote and ; missed in your post
    }else{
        //for the other elements
        echo '<li>'.$service->name.'</li>'; // quote and ; missed in your post

    }
$counter++;
} 
?>
```

**I don't know Yii, so if this below code:-**

`$services = TblWorksTags::find()->where(["active"=>true])->all();`

***Is giving you an indexed array (something like `Array(0=>'something',1=>'something else', ......so on)`). then you can use it's index itself like below:-***

```
<?php
$services = TblWorksTags::find()->where(["active"=>true])->all();

foreach ($services as  $key=> $service){ //check $key is used here
    if($key == 0){
        //if its the first element
        echo '<li class="active">'.$service->name.'</li>';  // quote and ; missed in your post
    }else{
        //for the other elements
        echo '<li>'.$service->name.'</li>'; // quote and ; missed in your post
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI  glad to help you cheers:):), BTW first one will also work